# pygame.transform.scale does nothing

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a large image `spaceship.png` (I think it's `512x512`) and I want it to show up as `32x32` pixels on screen.

```py
from time import sleep
import pygame as pg

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 800


def main():
    pg.init()

    screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

    player_img = pg.image.load('assets/spaceship.png')
    pg.transform.scale(player_img, (32, 32))

    for i in range(1000):
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(player_img, (i, 50))
        pg.display.update()

        # Check for QUIT event
        if pg.event.peek(eventtype=pg.QUIT):
            break
        sleep(0.1)
```

**Expected result:** the spaceship should show up as a small 32x32 image and move slowly across the screen.

**Actual result:** the spaceship shows up as a massive 512x512 image and moves slowly across the screen.

I thought `pg.transform.scale(player_img, (32, 32))` would set the width and height of `player_img` to `32`, but instead the call seems to have no effect whatsoever. How do I scale down the image?

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) doesn't scale the surface in place. A new but scaled surface is returned:

<s>`pg.transform.scale(player_img, (32, 32))`</s>

```py
player_img = pg.transform.scale(player_img, (32, 32))
```

Comment: Ohh lol I knew it must be something simple, thank you